# Autocomplete module name during import in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The stock python3 interpreter (e.g. on ubuntu) comes with autocompletion facilities built-in, which supports autocompletion for local and global variables.

However, it does not support autocompletion of module names when attempting to `import` a module.

Oddly enough, the interpreter's executable itself does seem to support autocompletion of available module names (both system and local ones), when one uses the `python3 -m` syntax.

**Is there an easy way to enable module name autocompletion in the python3 interpreter?**
(e.g. using the `rlcompleter` module in a `.pythonrc` startup script, etc)

Comment: Interesting question. Quick and dirty solution is to just use ipython, which already has all that set up.